# Fixed header hiding error messages

Tags: html, css, forms, validation, css-position

I'm having an issue where I have a fixed header on forms. when someone goes to submit that form, and that form has fields that aren't filled out correctly, the error message gets hidden by the fixed header which is floating above it.

Attached is a jsfiddle better describing the issue. Do not fill any fields in, just scroll down and press submit, and you will notice an error message appears above the fixed header, but the field is hidden

is there any way to offset the header for focuses like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/sD6Rk/

Here is the code from the fiddle:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header"></div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <form action="#">
        <label for="one">One</label>
        <input type="text" required="required" id="one" name="one" />

        <label for="two">two</label>
        <input type="text" required="required" id="two" name="two" />

        <label for="three">three</label>
        <input type="text" required="required" id="three" name="three" />

        <label for="four">four</label>
        <input type="text" required="required" id="four" name="four" />
        <p>scroll down for submit button</p>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

input, label {
    display: block
}

.container {
    height: 1500px
}

.wrapper {
    padding-top: 200px
}

.header {
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
}

#submit{
    margin-top: 500px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was something in jQuery. It's not the cleanest, but basically when submit button is clicked, focus on the error message and then stop the focus from firing over and over again afterwards. then reset every time submit button is clicked.

```
var error;
   $('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(){
        error = 0;

        $("input").focus(function() {
            if(error === 0){
                error = 1

                var target = $(this).offset().top;
                var header = $('.l-header').height();

                $(window).scrollTop( target - header )
            }
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question was send over for 4 years ago, but here is jQuery code:

```
var navhei = $('.header').height();
var navheix = navhei + 30;
document.addEventListener('invalid', function(e){
$(e.target).addClass("invalid");
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $($(".invalid")[0]).offset().top - navheix }, 0);

setTimeout(function(){
$('.invalid').removeClass('invalid');
},0300);
}, true);
```

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63qrvjgc/) example with your code.

I hope it will help some people, because I know it is very annoying thing.